# Firebase Auth and Vue-router

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I'm trying to authenticate a Vue.js app using firebase.

I have an issue where if trying to access a login-protected URL directly while logged in, the router will load and check for auth state before firebase.js has time to return the auth response. This results in the user being bounced to the login page (while they are already logged in).

How do I delay vue-router navigation until auth state has been retrieved from firebase? I can see that firebase stores the auth data in localStorage, would it be safe to check if that exists as a preliminary authentication check? Ideally the end result would be to show a loading spinner or something while the user is authenticated, then they should be able to access the page they navigated to.

router/index.js

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/example',
      name: 'Example',
      component: Example,
      beforeEnter: loginRequired
    }
})

function loginRequired (to, from, next) {
  if (authService.authenticated()) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/login')
  }
}
```

auth.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
    // firebase config
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

var authService = {

  firebase: firebase,
  user: null,

  authenticated () {
    if (this.user == null) {
      return false
    } else {
      return !this.user.isAnonymous
    }
  },

  setUser (user) {
    this.user = user
  },

  login (email, password) {
    return this.firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        this.setUser(user)
      })
  },

  logout () {
    this.firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      console.log('logout done')
    })
  }
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  authService.setUser(user)
})

export default authService
```

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p v-if="auth.user !== null">Logged in with {{ auth.user.email }}</p>
    <p v-else>not logged in</p>
    <router-view v-if="auth.user !== null"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import authService from './auth'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      auth: authService
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firebase always triggers an auth state change event on startup but it's not immediate.

You'll need to make `authService.authenticated` return a promise in order to wait for Firebase to complete its user/auth initialisation.

```
const initializeAuth = new Promise(resolve => {
  // this adds a hook for the initial auth-change event
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    authService.setUser(user)
    resolve(user)
  })
})

const authService = {

  user: null,

  authenticated () {
    return initializeAuth.then(user => {
      return user && !user.isAnonymous
    })
  },

  setUser (user) {
    this.user = user
  },

  login (email, password) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  },

  logout () {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      console.log('logout done')
    })
  }
}
```

You don't need to call `setUser` from the `signInWith...` promise as this will already be handled by the `initializeAuth` promise.

Comment: actually authenticated() still return Promise object not boolean though :(

Comment: @ilumin I'm not really sure what you mean. It's meant to return a promise. I specifically said *"You'll need to make `authService.authenticated` return a **promise**"*

Answer (score 8):

To build on [Richard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49302592/2617776) answer, for those who are using regular Vue (not Vuex)

## main.js

```
//initialize firebase
firebase.initializeApp(config);
let app: any;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
if (!app) {
    //wait to get user
    var user = await firebase.auth().currentUser;

    //start app
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      created() {
        //redirect if user not logged in
        if (!user) {
          this.$router.push("/login");
        }
      },
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

## router.js

```
//route definitions
//...
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    const loginpath = window.location.pathname;   
    next({ name: 'login', query: { from: loginpath } });
  } else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next("defaultView");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. I simplified it further - I didn't see the need to await the result of `firebase.auth().currentUser`. Once `onAuthStateChanged` has fired, I find that  `firebase.auth().currentUser` is ready to go.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same problem and ended up delaying the creation of the Vue object until the first onAuthStatedChanged.

```
# main.js
// wait for first firebase auth change before setting up vue
import { AUTH_SUCCESS, AUTH_LOGOUT } from "@/store/actions/auth";
import { utils } from "@/store/modules/auth";
let app;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
  if (!app) {
    if (user) {
      await store.dispatch(AUTH_SUCCESS, utils.mapUser(user));
    } else {
      await store.dispatch(AUTH_LOGOUT);
    }
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      i18n,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

And then in my route I check as normal and if they end up on login route I just push them to my overview page which is kind of my dashboard page.

```
#router.js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let authenticated = store.getters.isAuthenticated;
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!authenticated) {
      next({
        name: "Login",
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    // doesn't require auth, but if authenticated already and hitting login then go to overview
    if (authenticated && to.name === "Login") {
      next({
        name: "Overview"
      });
    }
    next(); // make sure to always call next()!
  }
});
```

Comment: requiresAuth is a meta field added to any routes that require authentication. It doesn't have to be named that but that's what I named it. You can add any additional fields in there you want to check. You could add a field named requiresAdmin and then check that field in your before check to see if they are admin.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) Use **beforeRouteEnter** from the component:

```
export default {
        name: "example",
        ....
        beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
            if (authService.authenticated()) {
                next()
            } else {
                next('/login')
            }
        },
}
```

2) use **beforeResolve** from the router.

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

    if(to.fullPath === '/example' && !authService.authenticated()){
        next('/login')
    }else{
        next()
    }
})
```

[Life-circle of Vue route guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow)

Answer (score 1):

To delay the auth state, all you need to do is

- a) Before the app is mounted, use the firebase auth onAuthStateChanged method.
- b) In your router file, add a meta to the parent route where you want to add the login protection
- c) Use a router.beforeEach for the authentication and how you want to redirect the users to.I will provide the examples for each case below:
  Stage a)

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        console.log(user)
        new Vue({
            router,
            render: h => h(App),
          }).$mount('#app')
        }
    });
```

Stage b)

```
    ....
    ....
    ....
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: { requiresAuth: true },//Add this
        children: [
            {
                path: "products",
                name: "products",
                component: Products,
            },
        ],
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Stage c)

```
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
        if(requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
            next("/")
        } else if(requiresAuth && currentUser) {
            next()
        }else{
            next()
        }
    })
```

I believe you're good to go this way.