# VUEJS + FIREBASE logging out after couple of hours on mobile devices. Staying logged in on Chrome Desktop

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, router, progressive-web-apps

Why is it that on Chrome I stay signed in over days(until i log out) but on the PWA version on iOS and Android and Safari on iOS i always get logged out after a couple of Hours.. even if I have set:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

Don't know how to tackle this issue, but here is some code of the most important. Tried this but didn't solve the problem: [Firebase Auth and Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648240/firebase-auth-and-vue-router/49302592#49302592)

MAIN:TS FILE

```
export const db = firebase.firestore()

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

//let app = '';

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  //  if (!app) {
  //app = new Vue({
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount('#app');
  //  }
});
```

ROUTER.TS FILE

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record =>      record.meta.requiresAuth)

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) next('login')
  else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('/')
  else if (!requiresAuth && !currentUser) next()
  else next()
})

export default router
```

Want the user to stayed logged in on mobile phone. Are Cookies or Session handled differently there?