# Vue JS LifeCycle Hooks/Firebase Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do a basic logout page however despite having logged the user out in the signout method AND directing the user to the login page which is different from the current page ( dashboard) the code in mounted() is still being run.

Results :

1. Alert (Successfully logged out!)
2. Alert (blablablabla)
3. alert(blablablabla) appears multiple times before I actually get directed to
   the login page

Ideal results

1. Alert (successfully logged out)
2. directed to login page

=====Dashboard code=====

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div v-if="email" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You are logged in + {{email}}!</div>
          </div>
          <button @click="signout" > log out </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import firebase from "firebase";

export default {
  mounted(){firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> 
  { if(user)
    {
        this.email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email
    }
    else
    {
        alert("blablabla")
    }
  })},
  data(){
      return{
          email:'',
      }
  },
  methods:{
      signout() {
          firebase.auth().signOut()
                  .then((user) => {
          alert("Successfully logged out!")
          this.$router.push('/login') 
        })
        .catch(err => {
          alert(err.message)
        });
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

=====Main.js=======

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App1 from './App.vue'
import {routes} from './routes';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history' // remove redundant # in URL
});

// before each navigation check if user is logged in
// if user is no logged in display login alert and direct user to login page
// else proceed
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (to.name !== 'login' && !isAuthenticated) { alert("Login first"); next({ name: 'login' })}
  else {next()}
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app', // cant find where element app is
    router,
    render: h => h(App1) //App referse to App imported in line 3
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind, the `onAuthStateChanged` callback function is executed **every time** the Firebase authentication is changed. It also doesn't stop unless you un-register it. It's best not to add it in a `mounted()` hook because it will be re-registered every time the component is mounted

Comment: Check out some of the suggestions in [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462) for hints on how to wait for Firebase Auth to initialise before trying to access the current user

Comment: Does this answer your question - [Firebase Auth and Vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43648583/283366)?